# Remove all characters before and including last /[:alnum:]\.php$] in txt file using VIM

Tags: vim, awk, sed

I need help removing all of the characters up to and including the last / on each line in a file either using VIM, sed, awk, grep....

An example line is:

```
/Backups/website.com/folder/file.php
```

I would like the output to be:

```
file.php
```

I tried:

```
%s/\([^[:alnum:]\.php$]\+\).*/\1/
```

But that produced:

```
./
```

...on each line.

Most other lines in VIM did not find the string.

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this in vim, it should work:

```
 %s/.*\///g
```

This will remove all characters upto the last slash(/)

Comment: So that I understand this: .*\/ = any character any number of times before a forward slash // removes is and g is global or all throughout the line.

Comment: You have understood it correclty @technerdius

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo '/Backups/website.com/folder/file.php' | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'
file.php
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's|.*/||' file
```

Output:

```
file.php
```

If you want to edit file "in place" add sed's option `-i`.